# iTextSharp How to Add Custom Properties to PDF-A?

Tags: c#, vb.net, itext, metadata, pdfa

Basically, i have original XFA file with many `Custom > Properties` and i can convert it to PDF-A but all of properties have lost after convert.

Here is my ConvertToPDFa Code:

```
 public byte[] ConvertToPDFa3(byte[] OriginPDF,byte[] FileStore,string XML)
    {
        //***************************************
        // Convert PDF to PDFa3 and Attach XML .
        //***************************************
        //Create Reader for Reading PDF in  byte[]

        using (var reader = new PdfReader(OriginPDF))
        {
            // Open Stream for Converting
            using (var Convertstream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                // New Doc for PDF/A-3
                Document pdfAdocument = new Document();

                //Init instance for pdfAdocument
                PdfAWriter writer = PdfAWriter.GetInstance(pdfAdocument, Convertstream, PdfAConformanceLevel.PDF_A_3U);
                writer.CreateXmpMetadata();

                if (!pdfAdocument.IsOpen())
                    pdfAdocument.Open();

                PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent; // Holds the PDF data 
                //Count original PDF pages and uses for pdfa-3
                PdfImportedPage page;
                int pageCount = reader.NumberOfPages;
                for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; i++)
                {
                    pdfAdocument.NewPage();
                    page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i + 1);
                    cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);
                }
                //Create Output Intents 
                ICC_Profile icc = ICC_Profile.GetInstance(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "res\\sRGB Color Space Profile.icm");
                writer.SetOutputIntents("sRGB IEC61966-2.1", "", "http://www.color.org", "sRGB IEC61966-2.1", icc);

                //Embedded File to PDFa3 
                writer.AddFileAttachment("XML for : " + certRefNumber, FileStore, XML, lblRefNo.Text + ".xml");
                //Close all file to finish 
                pdfAdocument.Close();
                reader.Close();

                //Test writes output in Phys path
                //File.WriteAllBytes(@"OutPDFa.pdf", Convertstream.ToArray());
                byte[] filledPDfa = Convertstream.ToArray();
                return filledPDfa;
            }     
        }
        // End Convert and Attached
    }
```

i tried get origin properties with these code :

```
static Dictionary<string, string> GetPdfProperties(byte[] originfile)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> propertyInfo = null;

        using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(originfile))
        {
            propertyInfo = reader.Info;
            reader.Close();
        }

        return propertyInfo;
    }
```

And Copy origin properties to PDF-A like this :

```
static byte[] CopyProps(byte[] fileinput,byte[] fileOrigin,PdfAWriter wr)
    {
            using (var rd = new PdfReader(fileinput))
            {
                using (var outp = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (var stamper = new PdfAStamper(rd, outp,PdfAConformanceLevel.PDF_A_3U))
                    {
                        var info = rd.Info;
                        Dictionary<string, string> propertyInfo = GetPdfProperties(fileOrigin);
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> property in propertyInfo)
                    {
                        info[property.Key] = property.Value;
                    }
                    stamper.MoreInfo = info;

                    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            wr.CreateXmpWriter(ms,info); //****error was here
                            stamper.XmpMetadata = ms.ToArray();
                        }
                    }
                return outp.ToArray();
                } 
            }  
    }
```

but found the error was inaccesable due to its protected level
Should i place the error line to another ?

Or

Have another solution for these problem ?
Please Help :(

i use iTextSharp 5.5.13

Comment: First of all, nothing in your code copies a xfa form definition. Thus, likely not only "all of properties" but actually the whole xfa form definition is lost. Furthermore, your choice does not make the pdf content *conform* to pdf/a, it merely makes it *claim* conformance.

Comment: Maybe i ask a wrong question. i just want to convert XFA  (Filled data) to PDFA (that i can do in the first method) and keep xmpdata or metadata or Advance Properties something else(my problems) i don't understand structure of iTextsharp enough i try to read documentation but there aren't help.

Comment: So you start with an xfa form but you don't want the result to be an xfa form anymore but instead have the former xfa form contents turned into a static pdf? And you want that static pdf conform to pdf/a? The former is called "form flattening" but itext 5 only supports flattening of AcroForm forms, not xfa forms. And for the latter you have to do more than merely claim conformance.

Comment: Could you suggest me what should i do?
1. Flattening XFA  to static PDF (with itext  right?)
2. conform static PDF  to PDF-A right?
3. .... anything else?  
4. last method is i need to sign Digital Signature.
Do i have to concern anything?
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Summary, PDF/A  can not write Custom property right? i tried to search an example but still not found yet :( please

Comment: *1. Flattening XFA to static PDF* - you can try [pdfXFA](https://itextpdf.com/en/products/itext-7/pdfxfa), an extention for iText 7, allowing you to flatten XFA forms to static PDF. *2. conform static PDF to PDF-A* - I don't know an iText tool for that. *4. last method is i need to sign Digital Signature* - you can do that using iText.